# Flatten an array of staff members

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a staff member array that looks like the following:

```
array:22 [▼
  "id" => "58"
  "userID" => "5"
  "title" => "HR Manager"
  "department" => "Human Resources"
  "employed" => "2010-05-11"
  "unemployed" => "0000-00-00"
  "active" => "1"
  "ts" => "2019-03-03 14:49:47"
  "name" => "James Smith"
  "email" => "james.smith@gmail.com"
  "staff" => array:7 [▼
    0 => array:22 [▼
      "id" => "45"
      "userID" => "5"
      "title" => "HR Administrator"
      "department" => ""
      "employed" => "2010-05-11"
      "unemployed" => "0000-00-00"
      "active" => "1"
      "ts" => "2019-03-03 14:49:47"
      "name" => "Jane Smith"
      "email" => "jane.smith@gmail.com"
      "staff" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:22 [▶]
    2 => array:22 [▶]
    3 => array:22 [▶]
    4 => array:22 [▶]
    5 => array:22 [▶]
    6 => array:22 [▶]
  ]
]
```

So each staff member can have staff under them reporting to them and it can go on for ever.  So what I want to produce is a flat version of this array, one where it looks like the following:

```
array:22 [▼
  0 =>  array:10 [
     "id" => "58"
    "userID" => "5"
    "title" => "HR Manager"
    "department" => "Human Resources"
    "employed" => "2010-05-11"
    "unemployed" => "0000-00-00"
    "active" => "1"
    "ts" => "2019-03-03 14:49:47"
    "name" => "James Smith"
    "email" => "james.smith@gmail.com"
    ]
  1 => array:10 [▼
      "id" => "45"
      "userID" => "5"
      "title" => "HR Administrator"
      "department" => ""
      "employed" => "2010-05-11"
      "unemployed" => "0000-00-00"
      "active" => "1"
      "ts" => "2019-03-03 14:49:47"
      "name" => "Jane Smith"
      "email" => "jane.smith@gmail.com"
  ]
]
```

The problem is I know how to get the data recursively from the database, but I do not know how to flatten that data into an array that looks like the above.

Comment: Your sample result isn't flat either, Jane Smith has a staff array...

Comment: @Nick sorry, I accidentally left it in, i've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive function to get staff from person:

```
function getStaff($personData, &$staffData) {
    if (isset($personData['staff'])) {
        $personStaffData = $personData['staff'];

        unset($personData['staff']);

        foreach ($personStaffData as $innerPersonData) {
            getStaff($innerPersonData, $staffData);
        }
    }

    $staffData[] = $personData;
}
```

---

```
$staffFlatData = [];

foreach ($personsDB as $person) {
    getStaff($person, $staffData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't use your code exactly but having the reference variables got me to the end!